# count different column values after grouping by

Tags: sql, oracle

Consider this table:

```
id name department email
1  Alex IT         blah@gmail.com
1  Alex IT         blah@gmail.com
2  Jay  HR         jay@gmail.com
2  Jay  Marketing  zou@gmail.com
```

If I group by`id,name` and count I get:

```
id name count(*)
1 Alex 2
2 Jay  2
```

With this query:

```
select id,name,count(*) from tb group by id,name;
```

However I would like to count only records that diverge from `department,email`, so as to have:

```
id name count(*)
1  Alex 0
2  Jay  1
```

This time the count for the first group `1,Alex` is 0 because `department,email` have the same values (duplicated) , on the other hand `2,Jay` is one because `department,email` has one different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant "two different values" for "Jay", you can use `distinct`:

```
select id,name,count(*) from (SELECT distinct * FROM tb) group by id,name;
```

You can use `count(*) - 1` to get similar results in your question.

Comment: that's good, is there a way to return back the `department email` columns for visualization of the values ?

Comment: You could run `SELECT distinct * FROM tb`.